# Startup script locks up Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: startup, xrandr

I ran Ubuntu 13.10 with a startup script that had three xrandr commands in it to add a screen resolution that Ubuntu couldn't detect. After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, the system freezes on startup. All I can do is enter terminal mode and type commands.

I think the problem is in the startup script. How do I disable my startup script from the command line?

I tried deleting the original shell file but apparently Ubuntu copied the file elsewhere when I defined it as one of my startup scripts, and the system still freezes on startup.

Comment: Where was your original file? Ubuntu does not, in general, copy scripts automatically. Look for a unique phrase in the file (eg. xrandr --output ...), mount /, then `grep -rH 'myuniquephrase .` to search the whole filesystem for any files containing that phrase.

Comment: It would be useful if you tell us **how** you installed the startup script. It is a system startup script, a DM startup script, one of your desktop startup scripts... it is not clear at all.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear but I'm a total n00b. I placed the script in my Ricky/Programs directory and then used a configuration utility to have it run on startup. I can't use the utility to remove it because the system freezes long before I can bring it up. I guess it would be a desktop script.

Comment: If you create a new user with `adduser` can you log in (graphical) as that user? You could also try [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration).

Comment: How exactly you made it run at boot? Where is the script? What's the content?

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.